# Run Custom Error using SubSonic

Tags: templates, subsonic

When I run the custom tool to create the cs files for SubSonic all the templates now inject a letter g to the top of the cs files.  To get this to compile I need to remove the g from the ActiveRecord.cs, Struts.cs, Context.cs and StoredProcedures.cs.  Anyone else run into this?  I am using MySQL.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Somehow some weird characters got in the templates.  I just re-copied the templates and all is good now.